# AVAudioMixerNode pan or AVAudioUnitSampler stereoPan properties not working to change left/right balance of sound output for AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code, which plays a single midi note, but I want to be able to adjust the balance/pan so that it only plays out of the left speaker or the right speaker or perhaps some combination. I thought changing "sampler.stereoPan" or perhaps "engine.mainMixerNode.pan" would do the trick but it seems to have no effect. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
engine = AVAudioEngine()
sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()

sampler.stereoPan = -1.0 // doesn't work
//engine.mainMixerNode.pan = -1.0 // doesn't work

engine.attachNode(sampler)
engine.connect(sampler, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0))

var error: NSError?
engine.startAndReturnError(&error)

sampler.startNote(65, withVelocity: 64, onChannel: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the pan of any node after it has been connected, the pan settings are defaulted again at the engine.connect method.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54049) the range of `stereopan` is -100 to 100.

Comment: Yes, same thing for `AVAudioPlayerNode.pan`, the header says "Range:      -1.0 -> 1.0" but realy it is "-100 -> 100"