# AVAudioEngine mainMixerNode pan not working

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I have the following method that plays a file.

```
let filePath = "/Users/fractor/Desktop/TestFile.mp3"
var file : AVAudioFile?
var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
var playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

    do {
        file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
    audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: file!.processingFormat);

    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    audioEngine.mainMixerNode.pan = 100 // No effect

    playerNode.scheduleFile(file!, at: nil){}

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("audioEngine.isRunning = \(self.audioEngine.isRunning)");
        self.playerNode.play();
        print("playerNode.isPlaying = \(self.playerNode.isPlaying)");
    }
}
```

The file plays fine, but the pan value has no effect. I've tried different values (-1, 1, -100, +100) and for all of these the stereo playback remains in the middle.

What do I need to do to make panning work?

Comment: Yes pan is documented to be between -1 and 1. However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716705/avaudiomixernode-pan-or-avaudiounitsampler-stereopan-properties-not-working-to-c/39793466) seems to suggest there can be a discrepancy between the documentation and reality. Still as I say, I've tried a number of values including extremes of the documented range.

Comment: I didn't notice pan on AVAudioPlayerNode and this does work, thanks.

Comment: Missing declarations added.

Comment: The post seems to be correct. -100 to 100 appears to be the correct range.

Comment: No idea why pan doesn't work on the mixer but you've solved my problem. Panning now works. Definitely give it as an answer.

Comment: I've tried it both on AVAudioPlayerNode and AVAudioMixerNode. Both do work as you suspected.

Comment: Thanks for being nonlazy, the opposite of me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the main mixer node is not usable in that way. You should introduce another mixer node and set its `pan`, or set the `pan` directly on the AVAudioPlayerNode.

Comment: I set the pan directly on my player node.  Same thing... no dice!

Comment: What worked for me was setting the "pan" property on the AVAudioSourceNode (using values -1 to 1) after calling the "start" function on AVAudioEngine. Setting the "pan" value before calling "start" had no affect.

Comment: @bberak Cool, give that as an actual answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "pan" property on the AVAudioSourceNode (using values -1 to 1) ***after*** calling the "start" function on AVAudioEngine. Setting the "pan" value before calling "start" had no affect for me.

```swift
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let sourceNode = AVAudioSourceNode { /* ... */ }
let mainMixer = audioEngine.mainMixerNode
let outputNode = audioEngine.outputNode
let format = outputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
let inputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: format.commonFormat,
                                        sampleRate: format.sampleRate,
                                        channels: 1,
                                        interleaved: format.isInterleaved)

audioEngine.attach(sourceNode)
audioEngine.connect(sourceNode, to: mainMixer, format: inputFormat)

do {
   try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
   print("Could not start engine: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

sourceNode.pan = -1 // -1 to 1
```